# Android Studio: Gradle project refresh failed

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I just installed Android Studio. I had to set the proxy to automatic for the installation to work. Now when I created a HelloWorld Project, I get the error:

```
Grade 'HelloWorld' project refesh failed
    Error: Connection timed out: connect
```

From what I have read, it might be a problem with the firewall. However I don't have the rights to add exceptions to the firewall. So before I ask the IT-Support, I want to check if it could be anything else. Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: You'll have to contact IT support if even after setting proxy in gradle and android studio and it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following link, but looks like you will need to contact IT as it clearly indicates the firewall issue.

[Android Studio – Gradle project refresh/sync failed : connection timed out](http://www.topjavatutorial.com/mobile/android/android-studio-gradle-project-refreshsync-failed-connection-timed/)